Is the set of points in $\mathbb R^3$ with exactly one rational coordinate connected?
Let
\begin{align}
S&=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:\text{exactly one of }x,y,z\text{ is rational}\}\\
&=\mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q\cup \mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q^c\cup \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q^c\\
&= S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3.
\end{align}
Is $S$ connected? Is it path-connected? The analogous problem one dimension lower (connectedness of the points in the plane with exactly one rational coordinate) can be answered by noticing that the line $\{(x,x)\}$ does not intersect your set, so it separates it into two connected components.
I suspect $S$ is connected but not path-connected because if we had an open set $A\subset \mathbb R^3$ which is not empty and not the entire space, we would want $\partial A\subset S^c$ and $S^c$ is the union of $\mathbb Q^c\times \mathbb Q^c\times \mathbb Q^c$ and a set of (Hausdorff, topological) dimension $1$. The first is totally disconnected, and the second is really small so I think constructing such a set $A$ is impossible. On the other hand, constructing a nontrivial path $\gamma:[0,1]\to S$ seems really hard because $S_1\cup S_2=\mathbb Q^c\times(\mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q\cup \mathbb Q^c\times\mathbb Q)$ so if you don't visit $S_3$ you can't change your $x$ coordinate, and the same for the other permutations.

Nice question! I think the Baire category theorem kills off path-connectedness, but the details are a bit messy; later today I'll try to fill them in.
